# hide element using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, hide

I have the following element nested among others, how can I get hold of this element either by css class or attribute 'button_uid' and hide this div?

```
<div class="segment_0" button_uid="btn" />
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS you can use

```
.segment_0 {visibility:hidden;}
```

or

```
.segment_0 {visibility:none;}
```